# Simultaneous ajax requests

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I am trying to run the remote function in the code below every 5 seconds.  It runs only once if I remove the frequency option. I tried `remoteTimer` function, but when I use `remoteTimer` function, some code of the script goes outside the script tags and I see that in the webpage.

```
echo $ajax->form(array('type' => 'post', 'options' => array('model' => 'Thing',
        'url' => array('controller' => 'things', 'action' => 'xyz'),'update' => 'dy4', 'indicator' => 'ldng', 'loading' => ( $ajax->
        remoteFunction(array('url' => array('controller' => 'stories', 'action' =>
        'keep'), 'update' => 'dy3', 'frequency' => 5))))));echo $form->input('a', array('type' => 'checkbox'));echo $form->input('b', array('type' => 'checkbox')); echo $form->end('RUN');
```

If in case, this cannot be done using CakePHP helpers, how can I do it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

Use remoteTimer in a very simple controller. See the page source and between `<script>` tags you'll get code that does what you want.You can use that code as value for "loading" option.

Comment: Thanks ghaxx, i tried that but its not working, belwo is my code, can you help me in figuring out y its not working, 

echo $ajax->form(array('type' => 'post', 'options' => array('model' => 'Thing','url' => array('controller' => 'things', 'action' => 'xyz'), 'id' =>'chooseDateForm',  'name' => 'chooseDateForm', 'update' =>'dy4', 'indicator' => 'ldng', 'loading' => 'show()')));


and below is the code for remote timer, 


fucntion show(){ //<![CDATA[
new PeriodicalExecuter(function() {new Ajax.Request('/bt/db/stories/keep', {asynchronous:true, evalScripts:true})}, 10)
//]]>}

Comment: Well... I meant the code between `<script>` tags that is actual javascript. :) So literally it's between `<script>//<![CDATA[` and `//]]></script>`. 
I wonder, too, if your code has more line breaks than the one visible in here. At least this one in here is not very readable.